# Windows 10 build 9860

Tags: windows-10-preview

Already tried to update 5 or 4 times, and it fails every single time.
I have tried to disconnect the all USBs while updating, and it didn't helped.
I'm thinking that my 'update file' which the Preview Build Updater downloaded may be wrong. or damaged. 
There is any way to delete it and let it download it again ?
I'm also connecting via wireless card. it also may cause it. but I'm switching to wire connections in two days.

Comment: Yes;  You fix this by reinstalling Windows 10.

Comment: Do I need to completely reformat ? or it can be done by 'upgrading' or something similar .. ?

Comment: Upgrade to what?  Your running a preview release of Windows.  This is sort of expected.  Be sure to report the problem to Microsoft so they can fix what cause this behavior.